# How to add character to content of post?

Tags: plugins, posts, categories

In per posts, there are **"oo/x/"**.

How to add "0" before "x" if `length(x) < 10` ?

Examples:

- x=12345678 ; length(x) = 8, so add "00" before x ===> x=0012345678
- x=1234567 ; length(x) = 7, so add "000" before x ===> x=0001234567
- x=123456789 ; length(x) = 9, so add "0" before x ===> x=0123456789

Do you understand ?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this question but I think you want to pad a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string If so, the question is off-topic here, being a pure PHP question.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to get the same length for all pagination URLs?

Comment: shortcodes? Can we see an example of content before and after?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the php [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and [printf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) functions.

```
$x = 12345678;
printf('%010d', $x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert X from `INT` to `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` inside MySQL.

Or, you could cast X into a string and pad it (to the left) with a 0.